# Universal approach to grep for both Linux and Solaris

Tags: linux, bash, solaris

I have a relative long collection of scripts that I'm currently evaluating, and making changes to the source in order to execute the same set of scripts in both Linux and SunOS boxes. Part of the code has a simple grep like this:

```
#Linux
echo -e  "\n foo \n bar \n test ok" | grep -Evw 'foo|bar'
```

My porting attempt works fine if translated as:

```
#SunOS
echo -e  "\n foo \n bar \n test ok" | /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -Ev 'foo|bar'
```

Is there a way to write a single statement in Bash to work in both scenarios? Or, should I be mentally prepared to start implemting additional if/else statements for each operating system?

In this case, it seems like /bin/grep can do both regex and word matching, but then with /usr/bin/grep we can only do word and not both:

```
$ echo -e  "\n foo \n bar \n test ok" | grep -Evw 'foo|bar'
grep: illegal option -- E
Usage: grep [-c|-l|-q] -bhinsvw pattern file . . .
$ echo -e  "\n foo \n bar \n test ok" | /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -Evw 'foo|bar'
Usage:  grep [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] pattern_list [file ...]
    grep [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] [-e pattern_list]... [-f pattern_file]... [file...]
    grep -E [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvx] pattern_list [file ...]
    grep -E [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvx] [-e pattern_list]... [-f pattern_file]... [file...]
    grep -F [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvx] pattern_list [file ...]
    grep -F [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvx] [-e pattern_list]... [-f pattern_file]... [file...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to write a single statement in Bash to work in both scenarios?

Yes.

> Or, should I be mentally prepared to start implementing additional if/else statements for each operating system?

No, this should be avoided when possible. In your case, everything can be done using standard commands so there is no need to add OS specific code.

Here is a portable way to do it. This should work on all Unix like machines:

```
PATH=`getconf PATH`:$PATH # Should be done once at the beginning of scripts.

printf "\n foo \n bar \n test ok" | grep -Ev '\<foo\>|\<bar>\'
```

`getconf PATH` is returning a PATH to POSIX compliant commands on all Unix/Unix like implementations.

`printf` should be used when formatting commands are needed, `echo` cannot reliably be used as its behavior is undefined, even under POSIX.

`\<...\>` is the POSIX way to specify word boundaries with extended regular expressions.

Note that I didn't use `$(getconf PATH)` but the older `` `getconf` `` syntax  because on Solaris 10, you might be running the legacy Bourne shell.

Comment: Now this is elegant, I like!

Answer (score 3):

How about putting something like that at the top of your scripts:

```
[ -d /usr/xpg4/bin ] && PATH="/usr/xpg4/bin:$PATH"
```

Then the following line will work on both systems:

```
echo -e  "\n foo \n bar \n test ok" | grep -Evw 'foo|bar'
```

The idea of course is to check if the directory `/usr/xpg4/bin` exists, and if does, we may assume that it includes a `grep` that supports the options that we want (presumably the GNU `grep`). So just add that dir at the beginning of `$PATH` so that it takes the highest priority.

Comment: I think this is a great idea --and will probably end up using this general approach... but unfortunately I still get an error:

`~$ [ -d /usr/xpg4/bin ] && PATH="/usr/xpg4/bin:$PATH"`
`~$ echo -e  "\n foo \n bar \n test ok" | grep -Evw 'foo|bar'`
`Usage:  grep [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] pattern_list [file ...]`
`[...]`
`~$ echo $PATH`
`/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin`

Comment: Can you add a `which -a grep` right after the `$PATH` line and run it in your solaris system to see what it prints?

Comment: -a doesn't seem to work, but it appears to be there:
`~$ which grep
/usr/xpg4/bin/grep`

Comment: Can you check what `getconf PATH` prints on the solaris machine?

Comment: `/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/SUNWspro/bin`

Comment: Can you verify that the this `echo -e  "\n foo \n bar \n test ok" | /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -Evw 'foo|bar'` works in the terminal?

Comment: It seams that it doesn't support the `-E` flag. But you mentioned in the question that it does. Can experiment with the `grep` flags to find out which one is causing the problem?

Comment: Taking the -w off fixes it. Maybe I should just live with it if word matching is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: Yeah, so the `grep` in that dir is not the GNU `grep`, so it is not going to be 100% compatible. But hopefully it will be easier to work with their differences, compared to the other, ancient `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put after the *shebang* :

```
grep_path=/usr/lib/gnu/bin # <- EDIT ME
PATH=$grep_path:$PATH

# will work on any platform with a GNU grep
grep foobar file
```